# changing request parameter in struts2 interceptor for security protection against xss

Tags: security, struts2, xss, interceptor

can anybody tell me how to change request parameter before passing to action in struts2 interceptor.

i want to do this to protect against xss attack. Also i want to do this in interceptor so it will be applicable for all request and no need to right individual code in each action class.

any other idea for security protection for struts2 based web application welcome

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit broad but I believe you want to work on the url of your request and any parameters included (GET) or your POST request.

For security guidelines you should check OWASP:

[https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheethttps://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

If you want to build further on these for your own application specific implementation then you need to:

1. configure your interceptor as described here: 
   https://struts.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html

You can alternatively apply interceptors per action as described here:

https://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html

```
@Interceptors('InterceptorName')
```

2. Perform any sanitization/validation actions on your input parameters.
   One way to trigger an interceptor is to mark your function with the corresponding annotation. e.g.: